# How to open a file which looks like unicode in emacs

Tags: character-encoding, unicode

I have a file in my C: drive on Windows named MSDELog.log and from opening the file with a hex editor I can see that there is a null character after each character.  But there is no indicator at the start of the file saying unicode or whatever the encoding is.

If I open this file with the Windows notepad it seems to recognise it and opens correctly.

If I open the file in emacs I see the text but every other character is ^@ - I realise this indicates a null character.

If I hit m-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system and try utf-8 there is no change in the view.  If I select utf-16 then I see a load of what looks like Chinese characters.

How do I view this file in emacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a file encoded in utf-16 little endian format without the byte order mark. You have to specify the endianness selecting utf-16-le when you use `revert-buffer-with-coding-system`

Comment: I wondered what le meant

Comment: LE means Little Endian. If the coding is not LE then BE, which means Big Endian.